# Hide whole div if no content

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my website I am displaying the upcoming events by applying below code and it only shows the future events. So whenever there is upcoming event it will be showing on my homepage.

However, when there is no event the title `Upcoming Events` appearing there with whole box. I have attempted to hide it when it is empty but it did not work because of my knowledge on PHP, I could not find solution for below.

I hope you guys can help me on this

```
  <div class="service-event widget-event widget"> 
       <div clear="event-items clear">

         <div class="event"><h4 class="title">Upcoming Events</h4></div>

    <?php

    $custom_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'event-category');

    if( $custom_terms ){


      $tax_query = array();


      if( count( $custom_terms > 1 ) )
          $tax_query['relation'] = 'OR' ;


      foreach( $custom_terms as $custom_term ) {

          $tax_query[] = array(
              'taxonomy' => 'event-category',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
          );

      }


      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'event',
                      'posts_per_page' => 5,
                      'post_status'    => 'future',
                      'tax_query' => $tax_query );


      $loop = new WP_Query($args);

      if( $loop->have_posts() ) {

          while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

          <div class="item">

              <div class="date">
                  <div class="text">
                      <strong><?php echo get_the_date('j') ?></strong><br>
                      <?php echo get_the_date('M') ?><br>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="info">
                  <h2 class="title">
                      <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/event/<?php echo $post->post_name ?>" class="underline"><?php the_title() ?></a>
                  </h2>

                  <?php
                  $cats = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'event-country');
                  $names = array();

                  foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                      if ($cat->parent) {
                          array_push($names, "<strong>$cat->name</strong>");
                      }
                  }

                  foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                      if (!$cat->parent) {
                          array_push($names, $cat->name);
                      }
                  }
                  ?>
                  <div class="location">
                      <i class="icon icon-location-blue"></i>
                      <?php echo implode(', ', $names) ?>
                  </div>
              </div>

          </div>
          <?php

          endwhile;

      }

      wp_reset_query();

    }?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to hide the *Upcoming Events* if no post is found..? if yes, you can move `<div class="event"><h4 class="title">Upcoming Events</h4></div>` just above `while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>` but do take care of the `<?` and `?>`.

Comment: @BagusTesa, thanks for your reply. Yes that's exactly what I want. I have moved above it but it does not work. I think i made mistake with closing tags. When I add `<?php echo '<div class="event"><h4 class="title">Upcoming Events</h4></div>'; ?>` to the code.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your code as below,

```
<?php
    $custom_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'event-category');

    if ($custom_terms) {


        $tax_query = array();


        if (count($custom_terms > 1))
            $tax_query['relation'] = 'OR';


        foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {

            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'event-category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            );
        }


        $args = array('post_type' => 'event',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status' => 'future',
            'tax_query' => $tax_query);


        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($loop->have_posts()) {
            ?> 
            <div class="service-event widget-event widget"> 
                <div clear="event-items clear"> 
                    <div class="event"><h4 class="title">Upcoming Events</h4></div>

                    <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                        <div class="item">

                            <div class="date">
                                <div class="text">
                                    <strong><?php echo get_the_date('j') ?></strong><br>
                                    <?php echo get_the_date('M') ?><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="info">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/event/<?php echo $post->post_name ?>" class="underline"><?php the_title() ?></a>
                                </h2>

                                <?php
                                $cats = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'event-country');
                                $names = array();

                                foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                                    if ($cat->parent) {
                                        array_push($names, "<strong>$cat->name</strong>");
                                    }
                                }

                                foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                                    if (!$cat->parent) {
                                        array_push($names, $cat->name);
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                                <div class="location">
                                    <i class="icon icon-location-blue"></i>
                                    <?php echo implode(', ', $names) ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <?php
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <?php
        }

        wp_reset_query();
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will only hide the header line. But the outer container will still be shown. If he wants to hide also the contains, all DIVs need to be inside the IF clause.